# How to print HTML Strings as Rendered HTML using PrintDocument in C#

Tags: c#, windows

I have a string variable which contains the source code of a HTML page. I have print this HTML page rendered view using source code string.

I am trying to print it using C# PrintDocument and WebBrowser control of Windows Form application.

Note:-

#### First using WebBrowser

WebBrowser is printing properly but I am not able set Printer Settings and PageSettings like PrinterName, Marging, Printing content height & width.

#### Second: PrintDocument

PrintDocumet provide better way for printer settings and page settings but it is print html source code as string not render html view.

*My Problem Is*

How can I print HTML View of give html strings with specifying few settings like PRINTER NAME, PAGE SIZE and MARGIN

Following is the source code that I have tried.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace QRCodePrinter
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string HtmlString = "";
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            HtmlString = "<html><head><body><h1>Praveen</h1></body></html>";

              string printerName = "Microsoft Print to PDF";
            foreach(string name in PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters)
            {
                if (name.ToLower().Contains("pdf"))
                {
                    printerName = name;
                    break;
                }
            }

            //Printer Settings
            PrintDocument document = new PrintDocument();
            document.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printerName;
            document.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = document.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes[0];
            document.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = new Margins(1, 1, 1, 1);

            document.PrintPage += Document_PrintPage;
            document.Print();

        }

        private void Document_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {         

            e.Graphics.DrawString(HtmlString, new Font("Arial", 10),Brushes.Black, 0F, 0F, new StringFormat());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The web browser control ought to have a ShowPageSetupDialog() method that you can call to set margins. Simiarly, there's a ShowPrintDialog() method. Do these not work for you?

Comment: I have to print content in a single click without showing PageSetup dialog. ShowPageSetupDialog() that provide settings to change visually I have to do programmatically without showing a dialog.